# PDO Update with variable table, column, row

Tags: php, pdo

I would like to build an ajax function that updates field variables in some tables.
The tables, fields, and rows are all variable and based on what is posted via the ajax function.

This is the code for my quickedit.php

```
define( "DB_DSN", "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$data" );
define( "DB_USERNAME", $user );
define( "DB_PASSWORD", $pass );

if(isset($_POST['table'])){ $table = $_POST['table'];}
if(isset($_POST['id'])){ $id = $_POST['id'];}
if(isset($_POST['field'])){ $field = $_POST['field'];}
if(isset($_POST['value'])){ $value = $_POST['value'];}

try {
    $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die("Connection Error");
}

try {
    $st = $con->prepare("UPDATE :table SET :field = :value WHERE id = :id");
    $st->execute(array(':table'=>$table, ':id'=>$id, ':field'=>$field, ':value'=>$value));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die("Query Error");
}
echo "table: ".$table." id: ".$id." field: ".$field." value: ".$value;
```

As you can see, I wish to dynamically select the table, column, and row.

I'm don't know a whole lot about exceptions, but none of them are being thrown
and it is successfully echoing the stuff at the bottom i told it to.

Comment: You can't use placeholders for table names or columns.

Comment: You can't use placeholders for table names or column names.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Any way to dynamically select tables then?

Comment: You can still use variables, but make sure they're properly sanitized. Also when you're catching exceptions, it's a good idea to echo out the message. `catch(PDOException $e){echo $e->getMessage();}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you can see, I wish to dynamically select the table, column, and row.

Yes, we see it.
And this is where your idea is wrong.

This is quite contagious disease every good programmer have to outgrow. You are trying to make Universal Updater. Unfortunately, although the idea of some automation is usually all right, too much automation can be a disaster.

Your application have to have an idea what does it update and why. All the queries have to be pre-written and only data part may vary. It's all right to build a dynamical update from the several  fields, but makeing even table name dynamical is too much.

As of your particular problem, **ORM** is what you really looking for. Look how it can be done with [Yii Active record](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/en/database.ar):

```
$post=$table::model()->findByPk($id);
$post->$field=$value;
$post->save(); // save the change to database
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build the original mysql sentence in the old way, using PHP to evaluate table and column names.  Then use PDO to bind values to the fields.

```
 $st = $con->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $field = :value WHERE id = :id");
 $st->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $st->bindValue(':value',$value,PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $st->execute();
```

Be carefult not to allow quotes or semicolons in the variables youre evaluating. It's fairly easy to perform an SQL injection that way.

Comment: And someone who upvoted it, burdens himself with responsibility for many possible injections too

Comment: If i did filter the fields, would this be an acceptable answer?

Comment: @RyanLutz how these fields supposed to be filtered? What if I'll send table=users, field=admin, value=true? there are not a single semicolon in these values. Someone needs to learn security basics and why balcklisting is not a protection at all.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll write one for each the. Even though this bit of code is only used by the admin, It best practice to do these thing right.

Comment: @RyanLutz take a look at ORM. [It is really what are you looking for](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/en/database.ar)

Comment: @YourCommonSense would yo say PHPMyAdmin is an "unacceptable" app? Because, you know, in PHPMyAdmin you are perfectly capable of  updating, truncating or dropping entire tables if that's what you need to do and, by the way, that is exactly what the app is intended to do. 

Without a context, it's irresponsible to deem an use case as unnacceptable. You're just patronizing others with your own self righteous assumptions.